# Save multiple Access Query resuts to separate sheets in single Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have queries that pull data and create a workbook for each query. The workbooks are written to local drive.

I manually add each tab/sheet to a Master workbook. I would like to have my code create this master Workbook with a sheet for each query result.

This Code creates 6 separate spreadsheets;

```
Function PROC_WithoutRACF()
On Error GoTo WithoutRACF_Err

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable1", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable2", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable3", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable4", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable5", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable1", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint


WithoutRACF_Exit:
    Exit Function

WithoutRACF_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume WithoutRACF_Exit

End Function
```

This code doesn't work

```
Function Proc_WithoutRACF_MySpreadsheet()
On Error GoTo WithoutRACF_Err

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable1", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable1"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable2", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable2"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable3", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable3"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable4", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable4"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable5", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable5"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyTable6", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "MyFileLocation.xls", False, acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MyTable6"

WithoutRACF_Exit:
    Exit Function

WithoutRACF_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume WithoutRACF_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to have my code also create this master Workbook creating Spreadsheet in the workbook for each Query result.

Comment: Why are you repeating code? And how does it *create 6 separate spreadsheets* when each line points to same workbook name. Look into [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access)

Answer (score 0):

The example below creates a **new** workbook with 6 sheets and through a helper method copies the queries to each sheet using the [Range.CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel) Method of Excel.

For simplicity, I've assumed the queries have sequential names i.e. *MyTable1*, *MyTable2*, *MyTable3* etc. as shown in your example. If that's not the case, this will have to amended.

```
Sub ExportToExcel()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim objApp As Object, objBook As Object, objSheet As Object
    Dim idx As Long

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objApp.Visible = True
    Set objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Add()

    For idx = 1 To 6
        With objBook
            Set rs = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("MyTable" & idx).OpenRecordset()

            'add sheet if needed
            If .Sheets.Count < idx Then .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            Set objSheet = objBook.Worksheets(idx)

            'call helper
            CopyFromRecordsetWithHeader rs, objSheet
            rs.Close
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CopyFromRecordsetWithHeader(rs As DAO.Recordset, objSheet As Object)

    Dim idx As Long

    'Create headers
    For idx = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        objSheet.Cells(1, idx + 1).Value = rs.Fields(idx).Name
    Next

    'Copy data
    With objSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
End Sub
```